# Determing the row from where the button is selected on grid view asp.net/c#

Tags: gridview, button

I have multiple buttons in gridview. How can i determine which particular button on a row has been selected ? How can i capture the row index??

I have used

```
 protected void crtButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
            string componentText;
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
            String componentName = row.Cells[1].text;              
     }
```

I have tried to generate buttons in gridview .aspx file through following code

```
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add to Cart">
                <ItemTemplate>  <asp:Button ID="crtButton" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" OnClick="crtButton_Click"/>
                </ItemTemplate>                
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

but it seems like it is not yielding the result. Can any one please help me.

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can get the row index of the clicked button:

```
protected void crtButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)clickedButton.Parent.Parent;
    int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
}
```

However, that's not the greatest approach since you have to know the level of the button. The best approach would be to use OnCommand in conjunction with a CommandArgument.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="crtButton" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" OnCommand="crtButton_Command" CommandArgument=<%# Eval("ItemID") %> />
</ItemTemplate>

protected void crtButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ItemID'. This is the error i'm getting when i try to use your code. Is theer a place i have to add itemid in the gridview columns ?

Comment: Just replace ItemID with the column/property name of whatever value you're trying to pass into your add to cart method.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the sender to a Button and then look at the attributes of the button:

```
protected void crtButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button Clicked = sender as Button;
```